# 'mvn' command not recognized on Jenkins Windows slave node

Tags: windows, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to build a Java project on a Jenkins Windows slave node, and when I try to run any `mvn` command on the slave from the Jenkins service, I get an error saying the command cannot be found:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
...
```

**NOTE:** If I log into the machine directly, running any `mvn` command works just fine.

**Windows Slave Node Setup**

> Maven is installed to the directory `D:\Apache\Maven`.
>
> Set system environment variables:
>
> - `JAVA_HOME` = `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40`
> - `M2` = `%M2_HOME%\bin`
> - `M2_HOME` = `D:\Apache\Maven`
>
> The `PATH` system environment variable is set to `%M2%;...`

From the Jenkins master's webpage, if I run the Groovy script `println System.getenv("PATH")` on the Windows slave node, I can see that is has the correct, expanded path for Maven's `bin` directory.

I can also verify Maven's `bin` directory can be seen by running the following:

> **Groovy Script:** `println "ls -al D:/Apache/Maven/bin".execute().text`
>
> ```
> total 14
> drwxr-xr-x    8 D-AUN-00 Administ     4096 Apr 20 12:35 .
> drwxr-xr-x    9 D-AUN-00 Administ     4096 Mar 31 11:46 ..
> -rw-r--r--    1 D-AUN-00 Administ      230 Mar 31 11:46 m2.conf
> -rwxr-xr-x    1 D-AUN-00 Administ     7085 Apr 20 11:49 mvn
> -rw-r--r--    1 D-AUN-00 Administ     6007 Mar 31 11:46 mvn.cmd
> -rwxr-xr-x    1 D-AUN-00 Administ     1796 Mar 31 11:46 mvnDebug
> -rw-r--r--    1 D-AUN-00 Administ     1513 Mar 31 11:46 mvnDebug.cmd
> -rwxr-xr-x    1 D-AUN-00 Administ     1843 Mar 31 11:46 mvnyjp
> ```

Curiously, if I run Maven with `mvn.cmd`, then Maven runs just fine:

> **Groovy Script:** `println "mvn.cmd --version".execute().text`
>
> ```
> Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T15:10:27-05:00)
> Maven home: D:\Apache\Maven
> Java version: 1.8.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
> OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
> ```

**Question:** Is there something I'm missing or haven't setup properly that would cause the `mvn` command to not be recognized?

---

**EDIT:** The build I'm running uses a custom Python bash script to invoke Maven.  The script is also setup to run builds for projects in other languages (PHP, Ruby, .NET, Node) and the tools for those builds all work just fine (`composer`, `bundle`, `devenv.com`).  However, I would think that how the build is performed shouldn't matter if the script console for the slave node returns the same error when attempting to run `mvn` commands.

---

**EDIT 2:** The more I look into this, the less I feel this has anything to do with Jenkins and more to do with how shell scripts are executed on Windows.  When I use the Script Console to invoke a Groovy Script on the slave node, Jenkins simply writes that out to a temporary file on the slave node and uses `sh -xe <script>` to invoke it.  When I try a similar approach directly on the Windows machine, every script-based command (e.g. `mvn`, `composer`) fails to run from within a shell script unless I prepend the command with `sh`.  This is unfortunate because the scripts I'm running may be run on a Linux or Mac node in the future, and I'd rather not litter it with Windows-specific commands.  I've tried this with both Git Bash and Msysgit, and I get the same results.  Next, I'll be trying Cygwin to see if that works...

Comment: What build step are you using to trigger `mvn`?

Comment: @Slav I use a custom shell-executed Python script to run on the slave that includes the Maven calls.  Everything in that script works except for Maven.  For some reason the Jenkins service running on the slave doesn't recognize `mvn` as a command, even though everything appears to be setup correctly.  FWIW, the Python script is also used to build projects in other languages on the slave (PHP, Ruby, .NET, Node), and all of those work just fine (`composer`, `bundle`, `devenv` with some extra hand-holding :P)

Comment: Ok, scratch that, `composer`, `bundle`, `npm`, and pretty much any other script-based command that previously worked returns the same error.  Our Jenkins master was recently upgraded, so I'm wondering if it's related to that.  I'm going to try uninstalling the slave service and reinstalling from the (now-upgraded) master.

Comment: Just make sure that if you are running on Windows slave, you use "Execute Windows batch command" to launch your Python script, rather than "Execute shell" (which is for Linux nodes). Have you tried, instead of Python script, just to type `mvn` in "Execute Windows batch command" build step?

Comment: @Slav Very interesting!  I tried that, and the batch script can run the `mvn` command just fine.  Why would that work but not shell execute?  Also, the shell command I'm running uses a slave-installed path of `#!D:\msysgit\bin\sh.exe --login -i`.  Do shell scripts get run with different permissions than batch scripts?

Comment: I don't think it's permissions, but rather environment inheritance. Honestly, I don't know anything about running `shell` on Windows environment. Have you tried (instead of trying to run `sh` on Windows) to run Python on Windows? Then you just need to use "execute batch" to launch the python script.

Comment: One last thing, considering that you are launching `shell` on Windows, and shell is very strict (case-sensitive, etc), try executing `mvn.bat` instead of just `mvn`. Windows would automatically try to append `.exe`, `.cmd` or `.bat` to files, but doubt that `shell` on Windows would

Comment: So running `sh mvn --version` works, but `mvn --version` doesn't.  I'm wondering if there's something awry with how the environment deals with extension-less files.  Also, Maven didn't come with a `mvn.bat` file - just `mvn` and `mvn.cmd`.  I downloaded Maven from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi), but the downloaded zip doesn't include any `bat` file.

Comment: I just tried latest Maven binary zip, and you are right, no `.bat`. Instead, they have `mvn.cmd` which is the same batch file, just a different extension. So, if you were running just `mvn` from "execute batch" or windows cmd, it would automatically execute `mvn.cmd`. However, since you are running from `sh` there is no such automatic thing. Like I said I have no experience with running `sh.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this is related to how shell commands are invoked on Windows in context of different tools.

**Jenkins Script Console & Groovy**

In Jenkins, when using a Windows node's *Script Console*, the Groovy script will invoke scripted commands as though they are Win32 application or BATCH script calls (e.g. `"mvn --version".execute()` will not work because `mvn` is a shell script - `"mvn.cmd --version".execute()` will work because `mvn.cmd` is a BATCH script).

When running Groovy script commands on a Windows node, commands that use shell scripts will need to be prepended with `sh` in order to be explicit.  This assumes your Windows node has a path to a shell executable in its `PATH` system environment variable.

*Sample Groovy script that works when invoked on a Windows node:*

```
println "sh mvn --version".execute().text
```

**Python on Windows**

I also realized that my Python build script suffers from a somewhat similar issue.  If you try and run a Python script on Windows that calls a shell script via `subprocess`, it won't work unless you include `shell=True` in the call.  Alternatively, you can prepend `sh` to the command to explicitly invoke a shell

> **NOTE:** This won't work for some tools like `bundle` for Ruby - for those commands, using `shell=True` only seemed to work.

*Sample Python script that works when invoked in a shell environment on Windows:*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.call("mvn --version", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The maven installation folder should be the same on both Jenkins master and client. Check if the folder location is same on both master and slave.

Other than that your env. properties are correct but check if you have added the properties under user or system properties. If you have added the properties under user and are starting the Jenkins slave as a windows service I don't think Jenkins picks up the values.

Comment: The master is a Linux box, while the slave is a Windows box, so I don't think it's possible to have Maven installed in both in the same directory.  I should also note that I'm not using Jenkins to run Maven but am instead invoking Maven from a script (I'll get this note added).  Regardless, I'd expect to be able to make `mvn` calls directly from the script console for the slave node.

Regarding the env. properties, everything is done under the system properties since the Jenkins slave service runs as a local system profile account (or something like that).

Comment: Ok..I thought you had configured the Jenkins job as a 'Build a maven2/3 project' project and invoking maven command directly from build step. What do you mean that you are invoking maven from script? Is it 'Execute Windows batch command' or 'Execute Apache Ant' or something else in Jenkins.
Also, in Jenkins, click on slave node->Configure->Node properties and check if you set correct values for 'Environment variables' and 'Tool locations'

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm executing a Python script using `Execute shell` and am attempting to run the commands from there.  The more I look into this, though, the less I feel that it's even related to Jenkins.  It seems that running any shell scripts from within a shell script are failing unless I add `sh ` on the front of the command.  When I use the Script Console on the node, Jenkins converts the Groovy Script into a shell script file and invokes it with `sh ...` on the node.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem add "#!/usr/bin/env zsh --login" in Execute Shell window Title.
It's very easy.

Comment: I use MAC PC not windows